# Can you create a SQL Azure BACPAC from a Remote C# Application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bacpac

I'm working on a tool to allow backup and restore of SQL Azure databases between various local & azure environments.

I have a working version where the BACPAC is created and directly streamed to my Local Developer machine.

But I haven't been able to find a way to create the bacpac and store it directly in Blob Storage using a remote client. Any of the examples I've seen either

- Stream the backup to the local PC, and then re-upload it to Blob Storage

OR

- Rely on having a worker role deployed on Azure to handle process

Is there a way to trigger the Backup Functionality that's available through the Azure Management Portal (Create Backup (BACPAC) directly to Blob Storage) from a remote client?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use SQL Azure Database Import Export Service.
You can find more about this service [here](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/).

For export functionallity you can then use this piece of code:

```
//Set Inputs to the REST Requests in the helper class          
IEHelper.EndPointUri = @"<address of database endpoint according to its location, e.g. https://by1prod-dacsvc.azure.com/DACWebService.svc for DB located in West US>"; 
IEHelper.ServerName = "<database_server_name>.database.windows.net"; 
IEHelper.StorageKey = "<storage_key>"; 
IEHelper.DatabaseName = "<database_name>"; 
IEHelper.UserName = "<database_user_name>"; 
IEHelper.Password = "<database_password>"; 

//Do Export operation 
string exportBlobPath = IEHelper.DoExport(String.Format(@"https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net/bacpac/{0}.bacpac", IEHelper.DatabaseName)); 
ImportExportHelper IEHelper = new ImportExportHelper();
```