# Backup and restore of Azure sql database using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to take backup of Azure sql database to my local system and then restore that backup to Azure sql database in c#. Can any body helps me out?Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This may be helpfull:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588450/can-you-create-a-sql-azure-bacpac-from-a-remote-c-sharp-application

Comment: actually i don't want to use blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database does not support creating .bak files on-demand. Azure SQL DB [automatically backups up all databases](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-business-continuity/) using native backups to enable you to Point-in-Time restore your database to any point in time within the databases retention period. However, these backups are not exposed and cannot be copied to the local system. To achieve what you want you can export a BACPAC file from a Azure SQL database to the local system using DACFx and also import it into a SQL Azure database from the local system. [This article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/dacfx-3-0-import-and-export-with-bacpacs/) may be of help.