# How to restore an Azure SQL Database to point-in-time using Azure management libraries for .NET

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

Below are for creating a database using Azure management libraries, and I would like to know how to restore an existing database to point-in-time on Azure.

```
// Crate Authenticate
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal("{clientId}", "{client-secret}", "{teantId}", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

// Connect Azure
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

// Create TestDB
var sqlServer = azure.SqlServers.GetById("{sql-server-Id}");
sqlServer.Databases.Define("TestDB").Create();

// Point-in-time restore ???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353771/backup-and-restore-of-azure-sql-database-using-c-sharp/38448216) SO question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved myself. Use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql rather than Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

private void RestoreToPointInTime()
{
    var token = GetToken("{tenantId}", "{applicationId}", "{appliactionSecret}");
    var sqlMgmtClient = new SqlManagementClient(new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(token.AccessToken)) { SubscriptionId = "{SubscriptionId}" };

    var myDb = sqlMgmtClient.Databases.Get("RestoreTest", "testsqlserver", "TestDB");

    var newDb = new Database
    {
        Location = myDb.Location,
        CreateMode = CreateMode.PointInTimeRestore,
        RestorePointInTime = myDb.EarliestRestoreDate.Value,
        SourceDatabaseId = myDb.Id
    };

    sqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate("RestoreTest", "testsqlserver", "TestNewDB", newDb);
}

private static AuthenticationResult GetToken(string tenantId, string applicationId, string applicationSecret)
{
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
    return authContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecret));
}
```

Comment: I asked a related [SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347543/possible-to-create-new-database-from-point-in-time-restore-using-azure-arms-sqlm)  Any chance you can provide input?

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to use REST API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20restore%20points

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Thanks. That is another option to do.