# Possible to create new Database from Point In Time Restore using Azure ARMs SqlManagementClient?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

Specifically looking for a way to perform point in time restore to a new Database, preserve the original database; ***using Managed API instead of REST API or Templates***.

Code I have so far:

```
    public async Task CreateDatabaseFromRestorePointAsync(
       string resourceGroupName, string serverName, 
       string databaseName, DateTime time) {

        using (SqlManagementClient sqlMgmtClient = GetSqlManagementClient())
        {
            DatabaseInner myDb = await sqlMgmtClient.Databases.GetAsync(
               resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName);            

            var newDb = new DatabaseInner
            {
                Location = myDb.Location,
                CreateMode = CreateMode.PointInTimeRestore,
                // RestorePointInTime = time; 
                Edition = "Basic",
                SourceDatabaseId = myDb.Id                   
            };

            var result = await sqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
               resourceGroupName, serverName, "BackUpRestoreTestDb", newDb);               

            // Throws "The point in time was not specified for restoring live database...'"
        }
    }
```

Found the following:

- This SO link [How to restore an Azure SQL Database to point-in-time using Azure management libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793003/how-to-restore-an-azure-sql-database-to-point-in-time-using-azure-management-lib).

And same link references a `new Database` instead of a `DatabaseInner`.  Cant find Database objects namespace.

- [Databases - Create or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases/CreateOrUpdate)
- [Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases).

**Edit 1:**
Tried the restore method specifically from [Brando Zhang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347543/possible-to-create-new-database-from-point-in-time-restore-using-azure-arms-sqlm#answer-46356113) but there are apparently namespace changes.  I'm using:

- .Net 4.6.1
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` version 1.6.0-preview
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent` version 1.2.0
- `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent.Models`

Getting *the namespace could not be found* for `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters`, `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties`, `DatabaseCreateMode`, `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse`.

`SqlManagementClient` exists in both `..sql` and `..slq.fluent` namespaces both of which do not find namespace for `.server` in the line `sqlMgmtClient.Servers.Get(resourceGroupName, serverName).Server;`

Searched [Microsoft's Azure Management Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/sql/management?view=azure-dotnet) with no luck.

But google found DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters and its namespace on a [spanish MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.databasecreateorupdateparameters.properties.aspx), which links to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion here is because there are 3 different API's:

1. `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` version < 1.0
2. `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` version >= 1.0 (API reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql?view=azure-dotnet)
3. `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent`, which is based on `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` version >= 1.0 and is intended to be a more human-friendly design but does not have as much feature support as the base .Sql library. (API reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.fluent?view=azure-dotnet)

Brando's answer is for the #1 API. To update the code for the new API (#2), it should look like this:

```
    // Create a database: configure create or update parameters and properties explicitly
    Database newDatabaseParameters = new Database()
    {
        Location = currentServer.Location,
        CreateMode = DatabaseCreateMode.PointInTimeRestore,
        Edition = databaseEdition,
        SourceDatabaseId = "/subscriptions/{yoursubscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{yourgroupid}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{sqlservername}/databases/{sqldatabasename}",
        RestorePointInTime = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-22T02:32:08Z"),//Restore Point time
    };

    Database db = sqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, newDatabaseParameters);
    return db;
```

The major differences are:

1. There is no longer separate classes like `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters`, `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties`, `DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse`. There is just one class `Database`.
2. The properties of `Database` are "flattened" so there is no inner `Properties` to set.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use this nuget package.

[Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql)

Then you could use below codes to achieve Point In Time Restore.

Code like this:

Notice, you need registry an application to get tenantId, applicationId, SecretKey, then with subscriptionId to get the authentication token.

About how to register, you could refer to these codes:

Main method:

```
        var subscriptionId = "subscriptionId ";
        var clientId = "clientId ";
        var tenantId = "tenantId ";
        var secretKey = "secretKey ";
        var azureSqlDatabase = "azureSqlDatabase ";
        var resourceGroup = "resourceGroup ";
        var azureSqlServer = "azureSqlServer "; 
        var databaseEdition = DatabaseEditions.Standard;
        var databasePerfLevel = "S1";

        SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));

        CreateOrUpdateDatabase(sqlManagementClient, resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase, databaseEdition, databasePerfLevel);
```

The get auth token method:

```
    static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
            credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        var token = result.Result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
```

The restore method:

```
    static DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse CreateOrUpdateDatabase(SqlManagementClient sqlMgmtClient, string resourceGroupName, string serverName, string databaseName, string databaseEdition, string databasePerfLevel)
    {
        // Retrieve the server that will host this database
        Server currentServer = sqlMgmtClient.Servers.Get(resourceGroupName, serverName).Server;

        // Create a database: configure create or update parameters and properties explicitly
        DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters newDatabaseParameters = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters()
        {
            Location = currentServer.Location,
            Properties = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties
            {
                CreateMode = DatabaseCreateMode.PointInTimeRestore,
                //DatabaseEditions.Standard;
                Edition = databaseEdition,
                SourceDatabaseId = "/subscriptions/{yoursubscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{yourgroupid}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{sqlservername}/databases/{sqldatabasename}",
                RestorePointInTime = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-22T02:32:08Z"),//Restore Point time
                //S1
                RequestedServiceObjectiveName = databasePerfLevel
            }
        };

        DatabaseCreateOrUpdateResponse dbResponse = sqlMgmtClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, newDatabaseParameters);
        return dbResponse;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Than you.  I have the following namespaces, `using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent.Models;`  on .Net 4.6.1;  However DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters , DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties and a few others, "could not be found."  This is [link to namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models?view=azure-dotnet) I believe it used to be in.  Would you mind specifying your framework & Microsoft.Azure.Management versions?