# Guidance on Managing Azure Website Deployments/Backups/Logs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Tasked with creating an automated Azure deploy and swap 'tool,' I would like use C# and Azure Resource Manager and add it to a WebAPI Server.
However, documentation seems limited.

For example, the following is the link for [ARMs BeginSwapSlotWithProduction()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.webappsoperationsextensions.beginswapslotwithproduction?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_WebAppsOperationsExtensions_BeginSwapSlotWithProduction_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IWebAppsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_Models_CsmSlotEntity_)

*Googling that method returns only 7 results!*

I see Azure PowerShell cmdlets very well documented.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#azure-powershell-cmdlets-for-deployment-slots
- http://ruslany.net/2016/10/using-powershell-to-manage-azure-web-app-deployment-slots/

And so is Azure Resource Manager with Templates.  <- Not type safe.

I have considered using Powershell inline in C# such as documented [here.](http://executeautomation.com/blog/calling-c-code-in-powershell-and-vice-versa)
But seems I am fighting the system.

Attempting to keep this question from being Opinion Based.  Are there other alternatives I have not mentioned here.

- Azure Resource Manager (Fluent Based)
- Azure Resource Manager
- Azure PowerShell
- Azure Resource Manager REST with (Weakly typed)Resource Manager templates.

Looking for a well documented, strongly typed way to interact with Azure basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to swap or deploy WebApp, you could use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/). We also could get more demo code from the [github Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net). About how to get the credential file you could refer to [Authentication in Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#auth-file-formats).

The following is the demo code.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"Credential file path");
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

//create WebApp
var webApp = azure.WebApps.Define(appName)
.WithRegion(Region.USWest)
.WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
.WithNewFreeAppServicePlan()
.Create();

//Deploy WebApp
 webApp .Deploy().WithPackageUri("packageUri");

//get WebApp
var webApp = azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup("rgName", "appName");

//swap WebApp
webApp.Swap("slotName");
```

Comment: Thanks, I was prompted to write the above after research being unable to find how to get the swap status.  Your code sample is awesome, I accomplished much the same with the 'non fluent' version.  See [Be able to obtain current swap status #3843](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3843) Being unable to find such prompted me to question using ARM.

Comment: Now having tried the Fluent approach.  I like it better.  I was steered towards not using fluent due to an MS Engineer's [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347543/possible-to-create-new-database-from-point-in-time-restore-using-azure-arms-sqlm#answer-46370430) to the effect of Fluent has less feature support.  I was previously creating 'Clients' for each Management namespace and the way you demonstrated Auth is much cleaner, tho I will use `FromServicePrincipal`.