# .NET Core 2 C# - Point in time SQL Azure restore

Tags: c#, sql, azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I need to programatically restore an SQL Azure database from a .NET Core 2.1 C# function. On [Recover an Azure SQL database using automated database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups) article shows how to do it with PowerShell or REST API. What I found [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347543/possible-to-create-new-database-from-point-in-time-restore-using-azure-arms-sqlm) does not work on .NET Core.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: If there's a REST API, you can do it in .NET Core, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the REST API and use `PointInTimeRestore` as the [CreateMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#createmode).

> PointInTimeRestore: Creates a database by restoring a point in time
>   backup of an existing database. sourceDatabaseId must be specified as
>   the resource ID of the existing database, and restorePointInTime must
>   be specified.

More info to be found here: [Databases - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate). And be sure to take a look at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#examples)

For instance, this would create a database from PointInTimeRestore:

**Request:**

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases/dbpitr?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "location": "southeastasia",
  "sku": {
    "name": "S0",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createMode": "PointInTimeRestore",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases/testdb",
    "restorePointInTime": "2017-07-14T05:35:31.503Z"
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
You could try the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.SQL NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/1.16.0-preview). Supported frameworks are .NET Framework 4.5.2 and Netstandard 1.4, based on the NetCore framework.

**Edit 2:**
Since the Microsoft.Azure.Management.SQL NuGet package is a prerelease version, please make sure you have the checkbox 'Include prerelease' ***checked***.

Worked for me:

[image: Include prerelease shows NuGet package]

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for your answer, but I can't use that package, it looks like it's not compatible with .NET Core 2. When I search it on the NuGet Manager, it only appears Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent.

Comment: @Matias please check my updated answer. Probably the Fluent package will work as well.

Comment: Thank you Rick, yes I was missing the prerelease check. I will try that now.